# Convex quadrilateral

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, contest-math

In a convex quadrilateral (the two diagonals are interior to the quadrilateral) prove that the sum lengths of the diagonals is less than the perimeter but great than one-half the perimeter.

Comment: The diagonals dissect the quadrilateral into pairs of triangles. Apply the triangle inequality to the appropriate triangles.